# absolute and conditional convergence

Tags: calculus

[image]

Hi! I am working on some online homework problems on absolute and conditional convergence for my calc2 class. I am really struggling with this one problem though. I set S= the summation of n=1 to infinity of ((-1)^n+1)/(n^5) so that a of n would equal 1/n^5. So that with the equation |S of n - S| less than or equal to a of n -1 would be equal to (1/(N+1)^5). So I solved (1/(N+1)^5) to be greater than 5*10^-4 so that N equalled 3.573051. Thus, I thought the smallest value of N would be 4. Then I set S equal to S of 4 which I solved to be: 1-(1/2^5)+(1/3^5)-(1/4^5) which needed up being .9718886638. Clearly I solved this entire problem wrong, because webworks is not accepting my answers for N or S. If someone could help to explain how to solve this problem that would be greatly appreciated because I am really confused.

Comment: Can you take a look at this? 

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

It will help people help you if you can use MathJax to format your questions.

Answer (score 2):

$$|S_N-S|\le |a_{N+1}|=\frac1{(N+1)^5}\stackrel ?\le\frac1{10^4}\implies$$

$$\implies(N+1)^5\ge10^4\implies N+1\ge7 \iff N\ge 6$$

Answer (score 0):

You can forget about the negative--that's not important because of the absolute value.  Then it's pretty simple--just plug in:

\begin{align*}
\left|S_N - S\right| \leq \left|a_{N+1}\right| \\
\Delta S \leq \frac{1}{n^5} \rightarrow n^5 \leq \frac{1}{10^{-4}} \rightarrow n \leq 10^\frac{4}{5} \leq 6.3
\end{align*}

$n$ has to be $\leq 6.3$ therefore $n = 7$ (otherwise it's not large enough).  This means:

\begin{align*}
n = 7 \\
S \approx \sum_1^7 \frac{(-1)^{n + 1}}{n^5} \approx 0.97213956203
\end{align*}